# Automatic Log off in Windows 7

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, group-policy

Is there a way of using group policy to set a Windows 7 AD attached desktop to logoff after 15+ mins?

I want the machine just go back to the login prompt after kicking off the user.

Comment: 15 minutes of inactivity or just logoff every 15 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a scheduled task that runs after fifteen minutes of being idle. Utilise the shutdown.exe command to launch.

Answer (score 0):

[Use Group Policy to configure a scheduled task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725745.aspx). You probably want it to be triggered by the Logon action

Set the scheduled task to use either "shutdown /l" or "logoff" to log the user off. It's probably good practice to also either configure a visible countdown timer to run at logon, or set another scheduled task to warn the user a minute before logging them off.